# Trouble creating events in Google Agenda from Google Sheets with a script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I created a script in a Google Sheet to create events in Google Agenda, in order to study.
My goal is to create many events like this : if i study on D0, the first event must be at D+3, then D+10 , D+30, D+60.

I get many problems :

- the script write "AJOUTE" in each box of the column (which means in french that the events are added to Agenda) , even if they are not completed with dates (I want to update for each chapter when it's done, and I do not do a whole chapter the same day!)
- the script doesn't care if the events are already created, so i get multiple events for the same thing...

My script is the following :

```
var EVENT_IMPORTED = "AJOUTE"; 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
var menuEntries = [{name: "Ajouter les événements à l'agenda", functionName: "importCalendar"}];
ss.addMenu("Agenda", menuEntries);
}

function importCalendar() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startcolumn = 1
var numcolumns = 30
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startcolumn, 1, numcolumns, 6)   
var data = dataRange.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) { 
var column = data[i];
var titre = column[1];    
var DateJ3 = column[2];   
var DateJ10 = column[3]; 
var DateJ30 = column[4];   
var DateJ60 = column[5];   
var eventImported = column[6];


var setupInfo = ss.getSheetByName("agenda");
var calendarName = setupInfo.getRange("A1").getValue(); 

if (eventImported  != EVENT_IMPORTED && titre != "") {  
var cal = CalendarApp.openByName(calendarName);


 cal.createAllDayEvent(titre, new Date(DateJ3)); 
 cal.createAllDayEvent(titre, new Date(DateJ10));
 cal.createAllDayEvent(titre, new Date(DateJ30));
 cal.createAllDayEvent(titre, new Date(DateJ60));

  sheet.getRange(startcolumn + i, 7).setValue(EVENT_IMPORTED); 

  SpreadsheetApp.flush();  
 }
 }
 }
```

Thank you in advance, i'm despair, i searched for hours but found nothing to help...